# How do I open the Minecraft Forge installer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

When I try to open the Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 installer that I downloaded, my computer doesn't open it normally but asks me to open it with another application. How can I open the installer? I haven't found out anything about how to fix this whether something is wrong with my permissions on downloads on my computer or if it's just the download itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it with Java. If it's not showing up in the list of apps to use, you might not have it installed.

If not, go to https://www.java.com/en/download/ and install Java.